# How to overide the onChange function in react-native-input-masked-text

Tags: react-native

i am using the `import { TextInputMask } from 'react-native-masked-text'`as a input filed for the mobile number.
And i have onChange function for my other input filed to change the value of the input filed when user type.
I want to use the that function in TextInputMask to how can i do so

This is what i am trying to do for now

```
            <TextInputMask 
             onChange={this.onChange}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            keyboardType={keyboardType}
            secureTextEntry={password}
            placeholder={placeholder}
        />
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a prop named "onChange" present in the TextInputMask. Instead you can override it by using "onChangeText". Just replace onChange with onChangeText. It will work.

Comment: Thanks buddy. But how can i grab the OnChangeText value from the  Textinput mask

Comment: You can grab OnChangeText value like this, 

onChangeText={modifiedText=> this.setState({ modifiedText})}